# Retrieve the number of edits made by bots, registered users and anonymous users for a Wikipedia article

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to retrieve the **number of edits** made by bots, registered users and anonymous users separated for a specific wikipedia article.

I know I can get all revisions for an article by the revision prop in the MediaWiki API, I was thinking to use rvprop=user to  return the name of the user who made the revision and do some processing on the retrieved data.

http://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%B3&rvlimit=500&rvprop=timestamp%7Cuser|size&format=xml

for anonymous users revisions the anon="" occurs always so I can count it, but for the bots I can't find a way, as far as I know the bots names are not always written in a standardized way.
Any idea how to do it? or an easier way maybe using another API to do this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [revisions API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#revisions_.2F_rv) lets you list the `flags` for each revision - they include whether an edit was marked as a minor or bot edit. For example, see [these revisions](https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=recentchanges&rcprop=title%7Cids%7Csizes%7Cflags%7Cuser&rclimit=3&rcshow=bot&format=xml).

However, it looks like the edits in your linked data set were made without flagging them as bot edits, either because those bots are not [approved bots](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%83%D9%8A%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%A7:%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A8_%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AA) or because they forgot to set the flag. In that case, you're quite out of luck. You still can filter against the term `bot` in the username or the [known list of bots](http://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allusers&aurights=bot&format=xml&aulimit=5000) in your wiki.